# How precise is a volumetric calculation made with satellite stereo par imagery?

Tags: satellite, volume

If I had an stereo par from Worldview-2  or GeoEye-1, how precise would be the calculation of mine's materials in cm3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen providers state accuracies around 20cm between two subsequent elevation datasets covering the same mine. Such accuracies require a significant number of calibration points from the site, and it is likely that it is dependent on the methodological approach to the retrievals.

As such, with a best case (or atleast something that providers state in their promotional material) scenario, the expected error is around 200 000 cm3 per m2.

Comment: Is there a formula to determine the accuracy and errors determined from the image resolution? example: I have a 40cm image, how can I calculate the accuracy and the error of that image?

Comment: @Thriskel - no. It depends on how accurately you retrieved elevation from the data. If you do not have enough ground truth to do a statistical evaluation, you will have no information to help you estimate the accuracy of the data that you have derived and thus, the accuracy of any volumetric measurements.

Comment: I'm understanding that if I have a 10cm DSM, I'll obtain a 10cm accuracy in the volumetric measurement, is that right?

Comment: @Thriskel - not really. The vertical (Z) accuracy of the DSM is not necessarily related to the spatial (X & Y) resolution.

Comment: @Mikkel_Lydholm_Rasmussen if I had 10 cm of vertical (Z) accuracy of the DSM, would I obtain 10cm accuracy in the volumetric measurement?

Comment: In theory, yes - but 10cm vertical accuracy is not easy to obtain.